# How to separate records with NULL values from a geoJSON file?

Tags: google-bigquery, geojson

I've a geoJSON file as below -

```
{"EFTA_FLAG": "F", "OTHR_FLAG": "F", "EU_FLAG": "T", "COAS_FLAG": "F", "NUTS_BN_ID": 108, "CC_FLAG": "F", "LEVL_CODE": 3, "FID": 108, "geometry": "{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[24.28752, 35.17601], [24.28513, 35.19078], [24.29281, 35.20274], [24.2949, 35.21629], [24.30594, 35.23965], [24.28578, 35.23943], [24.27087, 35.24888], [24.27403, 35.25674], [24.28072, 35.26354], [24.29232, 35.27115], [24.30861, 35.27614], [24.31421, 35.28196], [24.32534, 35.28467], [24.33098, 35.29074], [24.3305, 35.31241], [24.32346, 35.32514], [24.31741, 35.35377]]}"}
{"EFTA_FLAG": "F", "OTHR_FLAG": "F", "EU_FLAG": "T", "COAS_FLAG": "F", "NUTS_BN_ID": 298, "CC_FLAG": "F", "LEVL_CODE": 3, "FID": 298, "geometry": "{\"type\": \"LineString\", \"coordinates\": [[-6.34556, 36.79877], [-6.34397, 36.79998], [-6.34244, 36.80314], [-6.34244, 36.8053], [-6.3436, 36.81252], [-6.34495, 36.81596], [-6.35188, 36.8253], [-6.35296, 36.82927], [-6.35331, 36.83487], [-6.35398, 36.83836], [-6.35362, 36.85142], [-6.35296, 36.85741], [-6.34889, 36.87373], [-6.34594, 36.88804], [-6.34333, 36.89191], [-6.33989, 36.89527], [-6.33823, 36.89626], [-6.33107, 36.89884]]}"}
{"EFTA_FLAG": "F", "OTHR_FLAG": "F", "EU_FLAG": "T", "COAS_FLAG": "F", "NUTS_BN_ID": 355, "CC_FLAG": "F", "LEVL_CODE": 3, "FID": 355, "geometry": "null"}
```

While loading it into BigQuery using below syntax -

bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dataset.table_name data.json geometry:GEOGRAPHY,EU_FLAG,CC_FLAG,OTHR_CNTR_FLAG,LEVL_CODE:int64,FID:int64,EFTA_FLAG,COAS_FLAG,NUTS_BN_ID:int64

it throws error -

> Failure details:
>   - Error while reading data, error message: JSON processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 467; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error
>   percent: 0
>   - query: Could not convert JSON value to geography: Unexpected 'null' at position 0. Field: geometry; Value: null

I need to load the records with NULL in geometry too. How can I separate the NULL and not NULL records? And then how can load the NULL records too in BQ table?

Comment: Could you try using a null marker ==>  `--null_marker=null`

Comment: Hi Cavin, Tried that doesn't work. It works only with CSV files.

Comment: Can you create a schema file with this: [{"name": "geometry", "type": "geography", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "EU_FLAG", "type": "string", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "CC_FLAG", "type": "string", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "OTHR_CNTR_FLAG", "type": "string", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "LEVL_CODE", "type": "int64", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "FID", "type": "int64", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "EFTA_FLAG", "type": "string", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "COAS_FLAG", "type": "string", "mode":"NULLABLE" },
{"name": "NUTS_BN_ID", "type": "int64", "mode":"NULLABLE" }]

Comment: And then run bq load --source_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON dataset.table_name data.json <path_to_schema_file>

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Hi @rmesteves, Yeah I tried, It doesn't work that way too!

Comment: Did you get the same error?

Answer (score 0):

In JSON the NULL values should be encoded without quotes, just `"geometry": null`.

For this JSON file, I would load it to a temporary table, using `STRING` type for geometry field. Then convert it to `GEOMETRY` type using a query like

```
CREATE TABLE final_table AS
SELECT 
  * EXCEPT(geometry), 
  IF(geometry <> 'null', ST_GeogFromGeoJson(geometry), NULL) AS geometry
FROM temp_table
```